# JavaScript invalid size error after increasing max old space size

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, v8

I am facing the following error when I try to compute a sha256 hash of a ~300 MB big buffer using hash.js library:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffd6dc623c0
 1: 0xbe6ad1  [/mnt/user-data/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/node]
 2: 0x1e42f64 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [/mnt/user-data/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/node]
 3: 0xf06978  [/mnt/user-data/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/node]
 4: 0x10b48c2  [/mnt/user-data/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/node]
 5: 0x10b4b82  [/mnt/user-data/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/node]
 6: 0x12c3a5b v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/mnt/user-data/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/node]
 7: 0x1700579  [/mnt/user-data/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/node]
```

I tried increasing the available memory by using the `--max-old-space-size` param to an absurdly high value of 262 GB and it didn't help (the code was executed on a machine with half a terabyte of RAM):

```
node --max-old-space-size=262144 --trace-gc-verbose ./dest
```

This is the memory usage before the error gets thrown:

```
[1864454:0x6bfe770] Memory allocator,       used: 1662256 KB, available: 266822352 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] Read-only space,        used:    241 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:      0 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] New space,              used:      0 KB, available:  16109 KB, committed:  32768 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] New large object space, used:      0 KB, available: 587572 KB, committed:      0 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] Old space,              used:  15238 KB, available:   1485 KB, committed:  17024 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] Code space,             used:   1152 KB, available:    235 KB, committed:   1484 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] Map space,              used:    512 KB, available:    246 KB, committed:    776 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] Large object space,     used: 1610146 KB, available:      0 KB, committed: 1610204 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] Code large object space,     used:      0 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:      0 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] All spaces,             used: 1627291 KB, available: 267428000 KB, committed: 1662256 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] Unmapper buffering 0 chunks of committed:      0 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] External memory reported: 329446 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] Backing store memory: 329643 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] External memory global 0 KB
[1864454:0x6bfe770] Total time spent in GC  : 444.9 ms
```

It shows that plenty of memory is still available. Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong? Thank you

Comment: The library last updated 4 years ago?

Comment: There is a limit for array size and it's always `169220804` no matter how much memory you have

Comment: @Konrad was not aware of that limit. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @Orion447 didn't notice that it is no longer maintained. I will consider replacing it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an [array allocation error](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3728#issuecomment-1050127484). It doesn't matter how much memory you throw at node it can't allocate more entries in an array.

Use node [crypto's Hash](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/crypto.html#class-hash) and [streams](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/fs.html#fscreatereadstreampath-options) for large files.

```
import { pipeline } from 'node:stream/promises'
import { createReadStream } from 'node:fs'
import { createHash } from 'node:crypto'

async function collectString(readable) {
  let shasum = ''
  for await (const chunk of readable) {
    shasum += chunk
  }
  return shasum
}

const res = await pipeline(
  createReadStream('test.js'),
  createHash('sha256').setEncoding('hex'),
  collectString,
)
console.log('shasum: %s',res)
```